# Flask-Login "load_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'"

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am currently using Flask-Login for authentication, however I am getting an error that `load_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'` but when I debug my app, user_id exists and is being correctly passed into the `login_user()` function (and stored in the `session['user_id']` variable).

Below is my code for logging a user in and then navigating to home page:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    username = login_form.username.data
    password = login_form.password.data
    if user_details_valid(username, password):
        login_user(user_service.get_user_object(username))
        return redirect(url_for(‘home’))
    return render_template('login.html', form=login_form)

@app.route(‘/home’)
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template(“home.html")
```

The User model is as follows:

```
class User(UserMixin):

def __init__(self, username):
    self.username = username
    self.email = None
    self.password = None
    self.user_id = None

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

def is_active(self):
    return True

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

def get_id(self):
    return str(self.user_id)

def set_id(self, user_id):
    self.user_id = user_id

def set_password(self, password_hash):
    self.password = password_hash

def set_email(self, email):
    self.email = email
```

The stacktrace I am getting is:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 756, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
TypeError: load_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'
```

My user_loader is in the user_service class and is as follows:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(self, user_id):
    return self.collection.find_one({"user_id": user_id})
```

Comment: Have you provide a [`user_loader`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) callback?

Comment: Updated my post to include it. I think it is working correctly as when debugging the `session.get('user_id')` returns the user_id correctly, it only seems to be when loading the home page with the `@login_required` decorator the error occurs

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. When I initialize the LoginManager I forgot to pass the instance of the app as an argument.

app/**init**.py

```
#...
from flask_login import LoginManager
app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
login = LoginManager(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error I placed my `user_loader` inside my `__init__.py` file, as demonstrated in [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJGMOOSnHL0).

This is, however, not a perfect answer as neither [Miguel's guide](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins), the [RealPython guide](https://realpython.com/blog/python/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/#the-user_loader) nor [RunningCodes flask-login pymongo guide](https://runningcodes.net/flask-login-and-mongodb/) show this as the case, in fact both Miguel's guide and RunningCode's guide specifically have the `user_loader` in different parts of the app.

This solution does not make sense, as I have to access my database from inside my `__init__.py` which seems extremely messy but I was able to fix the error and properly login.

The error may be occurring because my `__init__.py` seems to be loading twice, I found another answer somewhere on SO that stated similar errors due to two instances of the app running.